# opening a network shared folder with a href

Tags: asp.net, html

I am trying to open a windows shared folder on my network using the  tag, however, I don't want a new browser windows to open or even reload my current one.  I've tried all the target values and they all redirect to another page.  Is it possible to open the folder without redirecting.  Even with another tag.  I am using asp.net.

thanks,

Comment: Can you show some code and explain what happens? I don't understand what you mean by "redirect to another page"

Comment: I have a simple <a> tag that looks like this <a href="//networkip/somefolder" id="link">link<a> when I click on the link it first opens a new browser window with nothing in it and then opens the windows folder.

Comment: So you want the user to click a button and a Windows Explorer window opens without the browser appearing to do anything else?

Comment: Correct that is exactly what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some success some years ago using an `iframe` with the source set to a network path.  That produced an embedded Windows Explorer window. However, that was on IE; I don't know how another browser might behave.